# Why can I not use height percentage inside a FlatList?

Tags: react-native

Im trying to implement a gridView, of 7 x 5 using a FlatList with numColumns.
Apparently my height: "20%" gets ignored so the grid is too small.
Providing a number like height: 200 , does work .....
But i want my layout to be responsive so this is not an option for me.
Does anybody see the problem or can explain to me how to achieve the grid?

App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import CalendarDay from './components/CalendarDay';

export default function App() {
  const [days, setDays] = useState([
    {date: "1", key:"1"},
    {date: "2", key:"2"},
    {date: "2", key:"3"},
    {date: "2", key:"4"},
    {date: "2", key:"5"},
    {date: "2", key:"6"},
    {date: "2", key:"7"},
    {date: "2", key:"8"},
    {date: "2", key:"9"},
    {date: "2", key:"10"},
    {date: "2", key:"11"},
    {date: "2", key:"12"},
    {date: "2", key:"13"},
    {date: "2", key:"14"},
    {date: "2", key:"15"},
    {date: "2", key:"16"},
    {date: "2", key:"17"},
    {date: "2", key:"18"},
    {date: "2", key:"19"},
    {date: "2", key:"20"},
    {date: "2", key:"21"},
    {date: "2", key:"22"},
    {date: "2", key:"23"},
    {date: "2", key:"24"},
    {date: "2", key:"25"},
    {date: "2", key:"26"},
    {date: "2", key:"27"},
    {date: "2", key:"28"},
    {date: "2", key:"29"},
  ])
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.calendarFrame}>
        <FlatList data={days}
        renderItem={({item})=>(
          <View style={styles.calendarDay}>
            <CalendarDay></CalendarDay>
          </View>
        )}
        numColumns={7}
        width='100%'
          
        />
  
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding : "5%",

  },
  calendarFrame: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: "#54f1da" ,

  },
  calendarDay: {
    backgroundColor: "#d5cf6a",
    width: "14.285%",
    height: "20%", //<-----------------doesnt work



  }
});
```

CalendarDay.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class CalendarDay extends React.Component { 
    render() { 
      return (
     
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View> 
              <Text>Day</Text>
          
          </View>
        </View>
     
      );
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex:1,
        flexDirection: "column",
        backgroundColor: "#3de2a0",
    
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so i used

```
<View style={styles.calendarFrame} /*set dayHeight*/onLayout={(event) => {
        this.setState( {dayHeight: event.nativeEvent.layout.height/5, key: this.state.key+1}); 
        console.log(this.state.dayHeight);  }}>
      <FlatList 
        data={this.state.days}
        key={this.state.key}
        renderItem={({item})=>(
          <View style={[styles.calendarDay, {height: this.state.dayHeight}]}>
            <CalendarDay></CalendarDay>
          </View>
        )}
        numColumns={7}
          
      />

 </View>
```

to make the elements 1/5 in height of the view. thanks for all the help <3

Answer (score 1):

because the calendarFrame is flex, so you can not get 20% height of the parent, that is depended on height of children. I think the solution is measuring the container height, then calculate 20% of it to set for each children.

You can measure by using onlayout, apply for the container.